# SCP from Remote Mac to SSH'd Server Fails

Tags: mac, ssh, permissions, scp

I've seen a lot of variants of this question but I don't think anything fits my exact situation.

I'm on a computer at work which is SSH'd into a server. While on this server I would like to SCP some files from my Mac at home.

I can SSH into my Mac from the server no problem with the normal command:

```
ssh username@ip.ad.dr.es
```

However when I try to SCP I get: **-bash: /usr/bin/scp: Permission denied**

I am using the command:

```
scp username@ip.ad.dr.es:/absolute/filepath/i* local/folder
```

I have also tried number -p flags.
There is only one account on my mac and it is the administrative account. I'm not sure if there are permissions issues or if it is because I am SSH'd into the server or if it is something else.

I am also able to SCP successfully from the server to my Mac when doing so from my Mac at home.

Any suggestions?

Edit: Additional relevant information originally posted as comments because I had a brain fart about protocol. (my bad).

Specifically related to my last sentence about being able to 'reverse' SCP: the following command works when I am logged into my Mac as the local machine:

`scp -P 22003 username@server.hpc.sch.edu:Data/path/i* /Full/Path/On/Mac/`

Running `ls -l /usr/bin/scp` on the server (local) returns the following:

> rwxr-x---. 1 root root 67648 Aug 31 12:40 /usr/bin/scp

Running `ls -l /usr/bin/scp` on the Mac (remote) returns the following:

> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 81360 Dec 1 14:45 /usr/bin/scp

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/scp` on the server?

Comment: Actually, what is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/scp` on both local and remote systems?

Comment: "I am also able to SCP successfully from the server to my Mac when doing so from my Mac at home." So, `work -ssh> server -scp> Mac` fails with above error, but `Mac -ssh> server -scp> Mac` succeeds ? That would be really "weird", either you can execute `/usr/bin/scp` on server or you cannot, regardless of where you `ssh` in from ... if `Mac -scp> server` works always, `ssh` to your Mac and then `scp` back to server.

Comment: On the Mac (remote) its: -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  81360 Dec  1 14:45 /usr/bin/scp
On the server (local) its: -rwxr-x---. 1 root root 67648 Aug 31 12:40 /usr/bin/scp

The server is administered by my university.

Comment: Apparently I can't edit comments after 5 minutes so to follow-up for @user2531336, the above command fails with the error specified but the following command works when I am logged into my Mac as the local machine:
scp -P 22003 username@server.hpc.sch.edu:Data/path/i* /Full/Path/On/Mac/

Comment: Note: you should have added these relevant information to your question instead of writing ill-formatted comments. It's not to late to fix this; you can  [edit] your question anytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The above command fails with the error specified but the following
>   command works when I am logged into my Mac as the local machine:

```
scp -P 22003 username@server.someserver:Data/path/i* /Full/Path/On/Mac/
```

So, from the server you cannot access `/usr/bin/scp` you get a "Access Denied" error. There may be many reasons for such an error, file permissions, for example.

Since you can `scp` from your Mac and you can `ssh` from the server to your Mac, I think that is what you should do, for now. `ssh` into Mac and `scp` from there.

To troubleshoot the problem on your server, first check that you have execute permissions on `/usr/bin/scp` on the server:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/scp
```

You see something like:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 84104 Jan 16 14:28 /usr/bin/scp
   ^  ^  ^
```

Basically, the file is owned by user `root` (with read, write, exec), members of group `root` have read and exec, so does world (everyone else logged-in)

If you have `x` (execute) privs on the command, use `scp -v` for increased verbosity (you can add more `v`'s, up to three, iirc), you might see a message that tells you what is wrong. You could also try `ldd /usr/bin/scp` to see if all dependencies are there and readable.

Comment: "first check that you have execute permissions on `/usr/bin/scp` on the server" – The OP did it before you answered, the result is `-rwxr-x---. 1 root root 67648 Aug 31 12:40 /usr/bin/scp`. Unfortunately it was posted as a comment, not edited into the question, you may have missed it. Still you can use this information to tailor your generic answer to fit the OP's situation better. Nevertheless +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's interesting because it seems it has group execute permissions and on this particular server typing 'groups' indicates my username is the group to which I belong as is the case with every user on this particular server). However it's a fairly secured university server so it is likely a permissions issue. SSHing works so at this point it's more annoying than keeping me from work. Thank you for your response. My reputation doesn't allow for a +1 but I appreciate it.